# How to extract striped region from an image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, orientation, image-segmentation

I am trying to extract only striped region from this image.

[image]

This is the region I want to extract.

[image]

There could be multiple approaches and perhaps their combination.

1. Use thresholding,morphology,grabcut operations to extract stripes
2. Gabor filter
3. Fourier transformation

How do I detect the orientation of the stripes from a fft2 transofrmation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import os
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
gray = cv2.imread('zebra.jpg',0)    
f = np.fft.fft2(gray)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))
imgs_comb = np.hstack([gray,magnitude_spectrum])
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('magnitude_spectrum')
plt.imshow(imgs_comb,cmap='gray')   
plt.show()
```

The set of images are unique with respect to their pavement type, paint recency.often time paint is worn out. Despite all these variations, FFT images are consistently giving me correct orientation and frequnecy. The result appears promising in that I could visually see the frequency representative of the pattern as well as their orientation(dominant vertical pattern in the image).

How do we use fft image for filtering out other regions ? 
Appreciate other suggestions using other approaches.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fft2, here's an approach using thresholding + morphology. The idea is to obtain a binary image through Otsu's thresholding then detect the horizontal lines using morphology. From here we draw the detected lines onto a mask then perform additional morphological operations to combine the stripes into a single contour. From here we find the bounding rectangle and extract the ROI

---

Otsu's threshold `->` Draw lines onto mask

[image]
[image]

`->` Opening/Closing `->` Detected ROI `->` Extracted ROI

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0 ,255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(opening)
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```